# Symbolic link renaming backup files

Tags: shell-script, shell, symlink, ln

I'm using backup files for when I create new symbolic link for files/folder. Because it's renaming existing symbolic files automatically on target folder like this :

Let's say `/home/main/Desktop` is empty and I run this command 5 times :

```
ln -s --backup=numbered "/home/main/test.jpg" /home/main/Desktop/
```

And `/home/main/Desktop` items are:

```
test.jpg
test.jpg.~1~
test.jpg.~2~
test.jpg.~3~
test.jpg.~4~
```

But I don't want it like this. I want to result like this:

```
test.jpg
test(1).jpg
test(2).jpg
test(3).jpg
test(4).jpg
```

Comment: `ln` does not natively support changing the format of numbered backups. You will have to use a script for renaming them afterwards or for creating the numbered links in the first place.

Comment: @FelixJN Can I use this command with pipe for renaming ?